# How to change header height in NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-navigationview

How can I change a header view height in the `NavigationView`? I have next xml:
**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/dlDrawerContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- Some data -->

    <!-- Drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nvNavigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**navigation_header.xml**

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_header"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:maxWidth="400dp"
           android:maxHeight="100dp"
           android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

But `NavigationView` ignores all dimension attributes and shows a header with default sizes. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `layout_height` value in your **navigation_header.xml**.

For example this will change the header height to 100dp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="400dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

Comment: How can I use wrap_content for `ImageView`. It doesn't work with `NavigationView`. My `ImageView` fills max parent height all same.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand what you want to achieve. Can edit your question and clarify what is the expected result, maybe with an image?

Answer (score 0):

It's late but I found it useful.
1- try to put your ImageView in a container like `FrameLayout`
2- then set FrameLayout's width and height `"match_parent"`
3- set height of `ImageView` to `"match_parent"` too
4- add `adjustViewBounds = "true"` to ImageView
5- add `maxHeight = "100dp"` to ImageView
so this way ImageView is set to `"match_parent"` but it is at last 100dp long in height

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            android:maxHeight="100dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```